# Thinking Sphinx won't build index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am currently trying to implement a search with Thinking-Sphinx (5.3.0) and Rails (6.1.4.2) running on Ruby 2.7.0 inside an Ubuntu 20.04.

When I run 'rake ts:rebuild' to build the index, it aborts with the message

> "NameError: undefined method `extend_object' for class` Singleton' Did
> you mean?  extended"

I have all prerequisites (gems 'mysql2' and 'thinking-sphinx', and Sphinx itself (2.2.11)) correctly installed, following the setup instructions at https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v5/quickstart.html.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is odd, because that part of Thinking Sphinx's code hasn't changed in almost a decade, and the extend_object method still exists on Module in Ruby 2.7 (and 3.0 for what it's worth). I wonder if another gem is getting in the way? Doesn't sound like you've done anything wrong though!

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, Pat. Before I tried Sphinx, I first gave Solr a chance, but that went compareably bad and ended with some weird Java errors when trying to start the search server. I will try to get Sphinx to work in a brand new app so that there are no other gems exept the standard stuff.